# Painting on my model doesn't work

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

I have UV unwrapped my model, as you can see on the right of the screenshot.
As you can see, i can only fill the model but i can't paint on it.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Blender Internal** Follow this quick step below and Save the file in UV Editor

1. UV unwrap the mesh.
2. Default material
3. In the UV Editor -> Click on New Image  (width x height and give a file name as(abc)) -> ok
4. In Uv Editor -> Image -> Save as Image <kbd>F3</kbd> give a name -> click ok.
5. Add a New material -> In the Texture Tab click on New
6. Below in the Textures -> Image -> Select from drop down image saved in UV (abcc)
7. Switch to Texture Paint -> Now you can paint

[image]

**For cycles** Follow this quick step below and Save the file in UV Editor

1. UV unwrap the mesh.
2. Default material
3. In the UV Editor -> Click on New Image  (width x height and give a file name as(abc)) -> ok
4. In Uv Editor -> Image -> Save as Image <kbd>F3</kbd> give a name -> click ok.
5. In the Material -> Surface -> Color -> Change to Image texture -> Select the created image (abc) from drop down.
6. Switch to texture paint -> Now you can paint.

[image]